# Formula to multiply all rows in a column after adding 1 to each one of them, and subtracting 1 after all of the products

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

How can I automate this formula to a large number of cells without needing to manually summing them?

I want to add 1 to each row in a column and then multiply it by the other rows with the same criteria, and after all, I want to subtract 1 of the total value, like this:

```
=(C2+1)*(C3+1)*(C4+1)*(C5+1)*(C6+1)-1
```

Answer (score 3):

[google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) only:

`PRODUCT` of `C2:C6`+1 enforcing array context with `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PRODUCT(C2:C6+1))-1
```

Answer (score 2):

THis should work:

=EXP(SUMPRODUCT(LN(C2:C+1)))-1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using two helper columns, where the first one contains the product, and the second the product minus one:

```
  | A | B |  C |          D |     E
==+===+===+====+============+======
1 |   |   |    |          1 | =D1-1
2 |   |   | x1 | =D1*(C2+1) | =D2-1
3 |   |   | x2 | =D2*(C3+1) | =D3-1
4 |   |   | x3 | =D3*(C4+1) | =D4-1
5 |   |   | x4 | =D4*(C5+1) | =D5-1
```

Dragging the formulas down should fill them in as expected. Column "E" contains the information you're looking for.